# idea intellij 11 версия выдает ошибку cannot find symbol SimpleIntege. Как пользоваться SimpleInteger?

Tags: java

Решаю задачу на codewars.com
В задаче используется SimpleInteger, как его импортировать или что нужно чтобы идея узнала этот тип.

```
String a = String.valueOf(dividend);
String b = String.valueOf(divisor);
BigInteger x = new BigInteger(a);
BigInteger y = new BigInteger(b);
BigInteger z = x.mod(y);
int i = z.intValue();
System.out.println(i);
return i;
```

Вместо int мне нужно использовать SimpleInteger не знаю как.

Условия задачи:

> Напишите метод, remainderкоторый принимает два целых аргумента dividend и divisor возвращает остаток при делении делимого на делитель. НЕ используйте оператор модуля (%) для вычисления остатка!
> Предположение
> Дивиденд всегда будет greater than or equal to делителем.
> >Примечания
> Убедитесь, что реализованная remainderфункция работает точно так же, как Modulus operator (%).

SimpleInteger представляет собой крошечную и неизменную реализацию целого числа. Его интерфейс представляет собой очень маленькое подмножество java.math.BigIntegerAPI:

```
#add(SimpleInteger val)
#subtract(SimpleInteger val)
#multiply(SimpleInteger val)
#divide(SimpleInteger val)
#compareTo(SimpleInteger val)

**import java.math.BigInteger; не помогает. 
Ошибка: cannot find symbol SimpleInteger.**
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с ним работать правильно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Выдает ошибку Ошибка: cannot find symbol SimpleInteger.

Comment: idea intellij 11 версия

Comment: откуда вообще вылез этот SimpleInteger? В задаче не упоминается. Судя по всему, его нужно самостоятельно реализовать, потому что такого стандартного модуля, вроде, не существует.

Comment: В задаче говориться так: SimpleInteger представляет собой крошечную и неизменную реализацию целого числа. Его интерфейс представляет собой очень маленькое подмножество java.math.BigIntegerAPI:

#add(SimpleInteger val)
#subtract(SimpleInteger val)
#multiply(SimpleInteger val)
#divide(SimpleInteger val)
#compareTo(SimpleInteger val)

Comment: Но если import java.math.BigIntegerAPI; Идея ругается. Это самой реализовать, а implement Integer? Какие есть идеи?

Comment: Проходит моя задача при таком решении.          
 public static SimpleInteger remainder(SimpleInteger dividend, SimpleInteger divisor) {
        // Code goes here!
        SimpleInteger z = dividend / divisor;
        return dividend.subtract(z.multiply(divisor));}  Но проходит только на сайте codewars.com на ПК в идеи не работает. Так и ругается на  SimpleInteger.

Answer (score 0):

Anna, в Вашей задаче класс SimpleInteger приведен для примера (как условность), этого класса в JDK нет.
Можно его реализовать самому, но никакого смысла в этом нет.
А для проверки в Intellij Idea просто замените SimpleInteger на BigInteger:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(remainder(new BigInteger("12"), new BigInteger("5")));
    }

    public static BigInteger remainder(BigInteger dividend, BigInteger divisor) {
        BigInteger z = dividend.divide(divisor);
        return dividend.subtract(z.multiply(divisor));
    }
}
```